# Update Changes to edited data on worksheet not working

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to edit data that is displayed in textboxes from a sheet, i can do all other necessary things such as add the data however my code attached does not update the sheet with the changes, i have tried using offset(0,1) but all that does is change one row with the ID number it is searching for as a row.
Box1 is a text box with an ID number in and is the main criteria my program runs on.

I am relatively new to VBA and have tried to search for solutions, but now i am at a loss without changing my whole code just to solve what will probably turn out to be an easy solution to someone more experienced than myself.

```
Dim findvalue As Range

Set findvalue = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Box1, LookIn:=xlValues)

cNum = 20
    For X = 1 To cNum
        findvalue = Me.Controls("Box" & X).Value(0, 1)
        Set findvalue = findvalue(0, 0)
    Next
```

Comment: Please clarify: Are you using `Worksheet` or `UserForm` text boxes? Where do you want to add the data from each`TextBox` to? Are your text boxes named correctly, e.g. "Box1" ,"Box2" or "TextBox 1" etc. An example/screen shot of what you are trying to accomplish, would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi GMalc i am using a Userform that is populated with data from 20 columns in a sheet to 20 controls, some textbox's and some comboboxs & trying to edit anyone of those controls with differing data

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim f As Range, x As Long

'always use "lookat" if you want an exact match
Set f = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Box1, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not f Is Nothing Then
    For x = 2 To 20 '<< no need to replace the value you just found
        Debug.Print "Setting " & f.Offset(0, x - 1).Address & " to value '" & _
             Me.Controls("Box" & x).Value & "' from 'Box" & x & "'"
        f.Offset(0, x - 1).Value = Me.Controls("Box" & x).Value
    Next
Else
    MsgBox "Id not found!"
End If
```

Comment: Hi Tim this nearly worked, however it only changed the data in the 2nd column it did not change any other data, i.e. col2 is first name col3 is last name this just changed first name not last name.

Comment: You will need to debug and find out where the issue is - I added a Debug.Print statement above - see what that gives you

Answer (score 0):

It does not make too much sense for me, but if you have 20 Textboxes (1 to 20), you can write the values stored in the textboxes in the range below where the ID was found using the following syntax. I hope you can get closer to solve your problem.

```
    Sub makeAndboxes()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim tbox As MSForms.TextBox
    'For the test creates 20 Textboxes with the name and value Box1, Box2, ..Box20.
    'The same text is in the range("A:A") somewhere to test
    For j = 1 To 20
        Set tbox = UserFormBX.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", "Box" & j)
        tbox.Value = tbox.Name 'Write the name in the box
    Next j

    Dim findvalue As Range
    'If it is the "A:A" range, it will be the cell where it is found
    Set findvalue = Sheet3.Range("A:A").Find(What:=UserFormBX.Controls("Box1").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If findvalue Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value: " & UserFormBX.Controls("Box1").Value & " not in Range(A:A)"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim cNum As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    cNum = 20
    For x = 1 To cNum
        findvalue.Value = UserFormBX.Controls("Box" & x).Value & " New text"
        Set findvalue = findvalue.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
    Next
End Sub
```